# Corona SDk - how to get a moving object to rotate and travel to a tap point?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am fairly new to programming but I am enjoying learning Corona by trial and error (mostly error!)

I am working on creating an Air Traffic Control Sim for a college project and have run into a brick wall on how to get an object (airplane on radar) to turn and travel to a tap point.

I am using the following code to move the airplanes:

```
local function moveAirplane1(event)

function cleanAirplaneRuntime()
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", moveAirplane1)
end

if Airplane1OnRadar == false then
cleanEI137Runtime()
end

Airplane1.x = Airplane1.x + math.cos(math.rad(Airplane1.rotation)) * Airplane1SPEED
Airplane1.y = Airplane1.y + math.sin(math.rad(Airplane1.rotation)) * Airplane1SPEED


end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", moveAirplane1)
```

This works fine and I can control the direction by adding or subtracting from the airplane.rotation value. However, what I want to do is allow the player to tap the screen and have the airplane rotate and travel to that point.

I have been trying to calculate the angle between the tap point and the airplane and then rotating the aircraft by the difference but there are so many permutations depending on what quadrant the airplane is in and what quadrant the tap point is in relative to the airplane that I'm wondering if I'm on the right track at all or is there a simple way to do this that I am missing?

Here is what I have been trying (apologies, it is long winded)

```
function vectorTo()


    function setVectorPoint(event)

        vectorPoint = display.newCircle(0, 0, 5)
        vectorPoint.x = event.x
        vectorPoint.y = event.y
        vectorPoint.alpha = 0.5

        airplane = EI159
        vP = vectorPoint
        airplaneHdg = EI159CurrentHeading

        Runtime:removeEventListener("tap", setVectorPoint)


        function angleBetween(vP, airplane )                -- Calculate angle between airplane and tap point

        airplane = Airplane1
        vP = vectorPoint

        xDist = airplane.x - vP.x 
        yDist = airplane.y - vP.y

        angleBetween = math.deg( math.atan( yDist/xDist ) )

            return angleBetween

        end
```

### -----------------------------------------------------------------

```
function vectorResult() 
    function round(angleBetween, precision)
        return math.floor(angleBetween*math.pow(10,0)+0.5) / math.pow(10,0)
    end

    roundVector = round(angleBetween,precision)


print("roundVector = "..roundVector)

--Quadrant 1

    if airplane.x < vP.x and airplane.y < vP.y then

        if roundVector < 90 then
            newVector = 90 - roundVector + 90
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 90 and roundVector < 180 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 180 and newVector < 270 then
            newVector = roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 270 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        end 


            function turnLeft1()
            airplane.rotation = airplane.rotation - 1
            print("Turn Left1")
            end

            function turnTimer1()
                --if airplane.rotation ~= airplaneHdg + newVector then
                turnLeftTimer1 = timer.performWithDelay(500, turnLeft1, newVector)
                --end
            end 
            turnTimer1()
        --end   
    elseif airplane.x < vP.x and airplane.y < vP.y then

        if roundVector < 90 then
            newVector = 90 - roundVector + 90
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 90 and roundVector < 180 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 180 and newVector < 270 then
            newVector = roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 270 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        end 

            function turnRight1()
            airplane.rotation = airplane.rotation + 1
            print("Turn Right1")
            end

            function turnTimer2()
                if airplane.rotation ~= 180 + newVector then
                turnOneRightTimer = timer.performWithDelay(500, turnRight1,newVector)
                end
            end
            turnTimer2()

--Quadrant 2    

    elseif airplane.x > vectorPoint.x and airplane.y < vectorPoint.y then

        if roundVector < 90 then
            newVector = 90 - roundVector + 90
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 90 and roundVector < 180 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 180 and newVector < 270 then
            newVector = roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 270 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        end 

            function turnLeft2()
            airplane.rotation = airplane.rotation - 1
            print("Turn Left2")
            end

            function turnTimer3()
                if airplane.rotation ~= 180 - newVector then
                turnOneLeftTimer = timer.performWithDelay(500, turnLeft2, newVector)
                end
            end 
            turnTimer3()

    elseif airplane.x > vectorPoint.x and airplane.y < vectorPoint.y then

        if roundVector < 90 then
            newVector = 90 - roundVector + 90
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 90 and roundVector < 180 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 180 and newVector < 270 then
            newVector = roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 270 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        end 

            function turnRight2()
            airplane.rotation = airplane.rotation + 1
            print("Turn Right2")
            end

            function turnTimer4()
                if airplane.rotation > 180 + newVector then
                turnOneRightTimer = timer.performWithDelay(500, turnRight2, newVector)
                end
            end
            turnTimer4()

--Quadrant 3

    elseif airplane.x < vectorPoint.x and airplane.y > vectorPoint.y then

        if roundVector < 90 then
            newVector = 90 - roundVector + 90
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 90 and roundVector < 180 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 180 and newVector < 270 then
            newVector = roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 270 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        end 

            function turnLeft3()
            airplane.rotation = airplane.rotation - 1
            print("Turn Left3")
            end

            function turnTimer5()
                if airplane.rotation < 180 - newVector then
                turnOneLeftTimer = timer.performWithDelay(500, turnLeft3, newVector)
                end
            end
            turnTimer5()    

    elseif airplane.x < vectorPoint.x and airplane.y > vectorPoint.y then

        if roundVector < 90 then
            newVector = 90 - roundVector + 90
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 90 and roundVector < 180 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 180 and newVector < 270 then
            newVector = roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 270 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        end 

            function turnRight3()
            airplane.rotation = airplane.rotation + 1
            print("Turn Right3")
            end

            function turnTimer6()
                if airplane.rotation > 180 - newVector then
                turnOneRightTimer = timer.performWithDelay(500, turnRight3, newVector)
                end
            end
            turnTimer6()

--Quadrant 4

    elseif airplane.x > vectorPoint.x and airplane.y > vectorPoint.y then

        if roundVector < 90 then
            newVector = 90 - roundVector + 90
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 90 and roundVector < 180 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 180 and newVector < 270 then
            newVector = roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 270 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        end 

            function turnRight4()
            airplane.rotation = airplane.rotation + 1
            print("Turn Right4")
            end

            function turnTimer7()
                if airplane.rotation ~= newVector then
                turnTimer = timer.performWithDelay(500, turnRight4, newVector)
                end
            end
            turnTimer7()    

    elseif airplane.x > vectorPoint.x and airplane.y > vectorPoint.y then

        if roundVector < 90 then
            newVector = 90 - roundVector + 90
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 90 and roundVector < 180 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 180 and newVector < 270 then
            newVector = roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        elseif
            roundVector > 270 then
            newVector = 180 + roundVector
            print("newVector = "..newVector)
        end 

            function turnLeft4()
            airplane.rotation = airplane.rotation - 1
            print("Turn Left4")
            end

            function turnTimer8()
                if airplane.rotation ~= newVector then
                turnTimer = timer.performWithDelay(500, turnLeft4, newVector)
                end
            end 
            turnTimer8()

    end
end
vectorResulttimer = timer.performWithDelay(800, vectorResult)

function removeVP()
display.remove(vectorPoint)
vectorPoint = nil
Airplane1dA.isVisible = false
timer.cancel(removeVPTimer)
end
removeVPTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1500, removeVP)

timer.performWithDelay(600, angleBetween)

end

function addEventVectorPoint()
Runtime:addEventListener("tap", setVectorPoint)
end
vectorPointTimer = timer.performWithDelay(500, addEventVectorPoint)

end
```

Thanks for any help or pointers in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the code DevfaR I was looking around and happened to find this and it is almost perfect for what I was looking for. There was just one small thing, the speed is different depending on how far away you tap. I changed in the code for it to always be constant, so if anyone else need it, here you go.

```
local W = display.contentWidth
local H = display.contentHeight


local bg = display.newRect(0,0, W,H)
local img = display.newImage("triangle.png")--make an image arrow pointing to the right
img.x = W/2
img.y = H/2

local getX
local getY
local travelFlag = true

local distanceX
local distanceY
local totalDistance

function getImageRotation(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    local PI = 3.14159265358
    local deltaY = y2 - y1
    local deltaX = x2 - x1

    local angleInDegrees = (math.atan2( deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / PI)*-1

    local mult = 10^0

    return math.floor(angleInDegrees * mult + 0.5) / mult
end


local function onTravel()

distanceX=img.x-getX
distanceY=img.y-getY

print(distanceX)
print(distanceY)

totalDistance=(distanceX*distanceX)+(distanceY*distanceY)
totalDistance=math.sqrt(totalDistance)
print(totalDistance)

    local function Flag()
        travelFlag = true
    end

    if travelFlag then
        travelFlag = false
        img.rotation = (getImageRotation(img.x,img.y,getX,getY))*-1
        transition.to( img, { time=totalDistance*5, x=getX, y=getY, onComplete=Flag } )
    end
end

local function onTap(event)

    if event.phase == "began" or event.phase == "moved" then
        getX = event.x
        getY = event.y

    elseif event.phase == "ended" then

        onTravel()
    end

end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", onTap)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created some pointers for you to make a reference using touch listener. When you touch to a specific position on the screen and then releases your finger, a transition will occur. You can copy this code and make new project to see how it works.

Here's the code

```
local W = display.contentWidth
local H = display.contentHeight


local bg = display.newRect(0,0, W,H)
local img = display.newImage("triangle.png")--make an image arrow pointing to the right
img.x = W/2
img.y = H/2

local getX
local getY
local travelFlag = true


function getImageRotation(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    local PI = 3.14159265358
    local deltaY = y2 - y1
    local deltaX = x2 - x1

    local angleInDegrees = (math.atan2( deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / PI)*-1

    local mult = 10^0

    return math.floor(angleInDegrees * mult + 0.5) / mult
end


local function onTravel()

    local function Flag()
        travelFlag = true
    end

    if travelFlag then
        travelFlag = false
        img.rotation = (getImageRotation(img.x,img.y,getX,getY))*-1
        transition.to( img, { time=2000, x=getX, y=getY, onComplete=Flag } )
    end
end

local function onTap(event)

    if event.phase == "began" or event.phase == "moved" then
        getX = event.x
        getY = event.y

    elseif event.phase == "ended" then

        onTravel()
    end

end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", onTap)
```

Comment: Thanks DevfaR. I was using "tap" instead of "touch" does this make any difference in my circumstance? I was still able to reference the x & y value of the tap point, I just can't get the object to rotate and travel to it. NOTE: I'm using enterFrame instead of transitions so that the object can be assigned a speed which can be varied by the user.

Comment: touch event has more listener that tap so i use it because its more efficient. i reedited my code and put a rotation in it just make an arrow image pointing to the left and use the image so it can rotate to the the direction you touch

Comment: Thanks again DevfaR. I'll try that out.

Comment: by the way the arrow must point to the right not left and if you want to change the speed of the transition you can change the time of it for example set it to 500 milisecond to make it faster just like this transition.to( img, { time=500, x=getX, y=getY, onComplete=Flag } ) or you make it higher if you want it slow happy coding :)